# How to force divs to overlap each other, but have height?

Tags: html, css

I have two or more divs which need to overlap each other (due some transition effects, i.e. switching tabs and slow disappear).

Below these two divs there is a footer element.

If I use `position: absolute` the parent element collapses and divs overlaps the footer element.

I can calculate tallest height in scripts. But maybe there is CSS way to keep parent element's height together with tallest one, but let children visually overlap?

**EDIT:** width of the children is unknown as well, as design is responsive.

```css
.parent{
 border: 1px solid green;
 position: relative;
}

.one{
 background-color: red;
 position: absolute;
 width: 300px;
}

.two{
 background-color: blue;
 position: absolute;
 width: 400px;
}

footer{
 border: 1px solid magenta;
 text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <div class="one">
  Div one to overlap. Height unknown, width unknown<br>
  Div one to overlap. Height unknown, width unknown<br>
  Div one to overlap. Height unknown, width unknown<br>
 </div>

 <div class="two">
  Div two to overlap. Height unknown, width unknown<br>
  Div two to overlap. Height unknown, width unknown<br>
 </div>

 <!-- ... --->

 <footer>
  Footer must be below all divs
 </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I've also tries to play with `float` and `overflow`. https://jsfiddle.net/dt7gvnsy/

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible with CSS only on elements with absolute position. Have a look at the answers of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821182/clear-absolutely-positioned-elements-with-css-possible) for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks Wis. I saw this. But maybe there is a hack to achieve same result, without `position: absolute`?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to achieve your goal, you can't use absolute position. Because absolutely positioned elements are taken away from the normal layout. Parent element doesn't know about its height.

you can do in the following way:

live [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rafee/oqskn104/)

CSS:

```
parent{
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.one{
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

.two{
  margin-left:-300px;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: blue;

}
footer{
  clear: both;
  border: 1px solid magenta;

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="one">
        Div one to overlap. Random unknown<br>
    Div one to overlap. Random unknown<br>
    Div one to overlap. Random unknown<br>
    </div>

    <div class="two">
        Div two to overlap. Random unknown<br>
    Div two to overlap. Random unknown<br>

    </div>

    <!-- ... --->

    <footer>
        Footer must be below all divs
    </footer>
</div>
```

**Limitations:**

- you have to know the widths of the divs
- you have to use same width either or use left margin value as the negative value of the larger width of the previous divs.

**Explanation:**

Floated elements sit side by side. If you use the negative value of margin-left, it will overlay on the previous div. Then you set clear property to both for footer which makes the footer stay at the bottom all the divs.

Comment: Thank you Rafee, this is almost a good solution, except, as you mentioned, I must know the width in advance. In my case parent element is responsive, so children's width may also vary. But I believe your offered solution may work in other cases.