# CSS How to set div height to 100% minus some pixels

Tags: css, html, resize, height

I'm trying to design a web page these days that is a bit hard.

I have three main divs. First one for header, another for footer, and third one for main content. Header and footer must be fixed in top and bottom of the page. Their place mustn't change with resizing of browser window. Third div must be in the blank space between those divs. It can resize to fit the page with window resize.

Height of main div must exactly change, because I want to place a Google Maps in that div, so the height of this div is important.

I tried so many things, but they were not successful. Setting `height` of the div to 100%(while height of body and html is 100%, too) was not the answer. Using a table (with three rows, two rows with fixed height, one row with variable height, with `height="100%"`) had some problems, too(in IE8, when I declared a `doctype`, the div in second row (with `height:100%`) didn't fit the cell anymore!).

Now I have no idea to do this work. What can I do?

**Note:** I prefer not to use CSS3, because compatibility with old browsers is important for me.

Comment: Add some code and maybe you get some answers. What about `margin-bottom: -99 px` or something like that?

Comment: There's a good answer here that uses pure CSS3 and works with Google Maps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434602/css-setting-width-height-as-percentage-minus-pixels

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

**HTML**

```
   <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    height:50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: black;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
}

#body {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #CCC;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
}

#footer {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0CF;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6M59T/

Comment: Thanks, but this code creates a scrollbar for page. I want some page without any scrollbars.

Comment: You are so near, but, but..., my problem is so confusing! I have to add some borders and shadows to that map. It's not working for me!

Comment: I think the best way is using jQuery. No way!

Comment: user1919959 well I'm not sure what you're talking about at this point. @Ruffo lol.

Answer (score 0):

Use a set height for your header, and use [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) to keep your footer a set height and aligned to the bottom as well. The space in between should then always be the right height.

Comment: Can you explain more?I think I did something like this before, but it was not useful.

Comment: @user1919959 It's a bit unclear as to what you need, but if the layout on the link is what you wanted, i.e. the header and footer have set heights and are aligned to their respective sides of the page, and the body will change height depending on the content or size of the window, then that is my best recommendation.

Comment: Ok, I know, but this method creates scrollbar and it's not my goal. Am I wrong?

Comment: @user1919959 I don't see any scrollbar on the example site - did you actually implement it and get a scrollbar? You shouldn't

Comment: You are right, but the problem is that we can't have a div in the middle of two divs with height. Height is so important, because of google maps. I think JQuery is the best way.

Comment: @user1919959 [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/PMVy2/) of sticky footer, if that's at all helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the well known [Clearfix hack](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) to handle height issues, because you need to "clear" parents elements to get that full 100% height you need.

Comment: I can't understand how can I use it for my problem??!!

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the shortcomings of css. You cannot accomplish what you want using just those three divs. You need to use additional divs to offset the height of your header and footer. Here is how to solve this:

```
<body style="height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <div id="header" style="height:50px; position: relative; z-index: inherit; background-color:lightblue;"></div>
    <div id="content" style="height:100%; margin:-50px 0 -70px 0; background-color:wheat">
        <div id="header-offset" style="height:50px;"></div>
        <div id="footer-offset" style="height:70px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" style="height:70px; background-color:lightblue;"></div>
</body>
```