# How to perform arithmetic operations in CSS?

Tags: css

I want to know how can I achieve an arithmetic operation in CSS.

**For example**:
I want to align two divs side by side each having width of 50% and I want to give border on these divs. I want to write my rule like this.

```
#container {
    width: 50% - 1px; // I know this does not work.
}
```

Why do browsers not support such arithmetic operations in CSS ?

And, How can I get this to work ?

Comment: “Why” questions are generally non-constructive. You should have presented your use case as a technical question (and written the title accordingly) calling for solutions, instead of “Just want to know why ?”.

Comment: Thanks @JukkaK.Korpela Will take care from next time.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It already [exists](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation); You can use the CSS3 `calc()` notation:

```
div {
    background: olive;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

div > div {
    background: azure;
    height: calc(100% - 10px);
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NejMF/

<sup>Note: It's only supported in [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/calc) (IE9+) and has only recently been adopted by mobile browsers.</sup>

Comment: @blunderboy For browser prefixes, see the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434602/css-setting-width-height-as-percentage-minus-pixels#answer-14101451

Comment: `calc` is [poorly supported in mobile browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc), IE8, Safari <6, and Opera. Try using `box-sizing: border-box` instead.

Answer (score 10):

Use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) on your `<div>` to make borders part of the width calculation. The default value for `box-sizing` is `content-box`, which does not include padding or border in the `width` attribute.

```
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Paul Irish comments on the use of `calc()` and [suggests using border-box](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) because it better matches our mental model of "width".

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with a CSS precompiler. `LESS` ans `Sass` are very popular.
You can write it just the way you did it in the example above.

http://www.lesscss.org/

LESS is more easy to handle when you are a designer. For programmers and Ruby (on Rails) developers Sass maybe the better choice.