# Fixed Sidebar and Footer

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve a fixed sidebar where the footer should not interfere with the fixed sidebar.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="sidebar"> <!-- Fixed sidebar -->
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <!-- Long article -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: What's the status of your issue ? Is it fixed ? Did our answers help at all ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to fixate elements to viewport.

```
.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px; /* below the header */
  height: calc(100% - 200px); /* substract the height of the header and footer */
}
```

You should have a look at this answer for the CSS3 calc-function: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14101451

Comment: I would suggest using `max-height` instead of `height`.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect Google's code for this page, you'll see that the element is set to `position: fixed` once you've scrolled a certain amount as well as a `top` value set to the header's height.

It's `max-height` is lowered as the window's height lowers.

If you're satisfied with its [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sticky) you could try `position: sticky` although I would advise not too as it's still only truly compatible with Firefox & Safari's latest versions.

You'll have to set your sidebar to `position: fixed` and adjust its position values using JavaScript on scroll. Or set it to fixed from the get-go and use `z-index` on your footer to cover it.