# 100% height minus header?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a layout for an admin panel, but I dont know how to get the #nav and #content container always at 100% of the browser window. I don't understand the inherit of 100% height attributes, could someone explain it more clearly?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>index.htm</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

        <div id="header">
            <img src="./img/header_logo.png" alt="bla"/>
        </div><!-- #header -->
        <div id="nav">
        </div><!-- #nav -->
        <div id="content">
        asfdg
        </div><!-- #content -->
        <div class="clear">
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
    html, body{
    font-family: Helvetica, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 100%;
}
img{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border-width: 0px;
}
#wrapper{

}
#header{
    background: url(img/header_bg.png) repeat-x;
    height: 65px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
#nav{
    width: 235px;
    float: left; 
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-right: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    height: 100%;

}
#content{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    padding: 15px;

}
.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: What browsers do you need to support (in particular IE)?

Comment: unfortunately, height:100% relies on the height of the parent container being explicitly defined.  Otherwise, the browser engine has no idea what 100% is.  The best way to have this is through javascript with a window resize event.

Comment: +1. 100% minus whatever would be a nice feature in CSS! E.g. in situations when you need 100% minus some padding/border... Well, this was the biggest advantage of the old non-standard IE box model :-)

Comment: How does Wordpress manage that? With deactivated Javascript ist also expands both divs to 100% http://cl.ly/FvS4

Comment: This article may help you. The OP uses a fixed header though - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192783/css-how-to-set-div-height-100-minus-npx

Comment: @Tomas Have you ever played with the box-sizing CSS property? Example http://jsfiddle.net/post_erasmus/gP5bc/.  It lets you set a box dimensions and force padding and border (or just padding) to rendered from the box dimensions inward.

Comment: @post_erasmus, nice, but it is not cross-browser compliant, is it?

Comment: @Tomas the padding-box value is firefox/gecko only, but if you include the -webkit-box-sizing property, safari, chrome, firefox, and IE8+ all support border-box.

Comment: @post_erasmus, well, but I'm not feeling good about using non-standard things... that will completely broke the page for other browsers.

Comment: Allright, I didn't achieved my goal yet. That's what I want: http://cl.ly/FxTP. I tried cssstickyfooter, the and I don't work as I expected... Any other ideas?

Comment: @nohayeye Did you check out my jsfiddle link in the answer below?  I believe it matches what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Bojin Li Oh yes, sorry!

Answer (score 171, accepted):

If your browser supports CSS3, try using the CSS element `Calc()`

```
height: calc(100% - 65px);
```

you might also want to adding browser compatibility options:

```
height: -o-calc(100% - 65px); /* opera */
height: -webkit-calc(100% - 65px); /* google, safari */
height: -moz-calc(100% - 65px); /* firefox */
```

also make sure you have spaces between values, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16291105/427622

Comment: This also works perfectly with `100vh` (viewport height).

Comment: beware, vh does not work well with Safari.

Comment: @kingPuppy - vh seems to be reliably supported in Safari, with only iOS 7.1 requiring a slight workaround: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: Quick note: the spaces between the calc variables are required, calc(100%-65px) won't work.

Comment: Interestingly, with tailwindcss, the spaces between calc variables are *not* allowed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69870451/3518049

Answer (score 16):

As mentioned in the comments height:100% relies on the height of the parent container being explicitly defined.  One way to achieve what you want is to use absolute/relative positioning, and specifying the left/right/top/bottom properties to "stretch" the content out to fill the available space. I have implemented what I gather you want to achieve [in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEDX8/1/).  Try resizing the Result window and you will see the content resizes automatically.

The limitation of this approach in your case is that you have to specify an explicit margin-top on the parent container to offset its contents down to make room for the header content.  You can make it dynamic if you throw in javascript though.

Comment: but how to make sure the neither the Navbar nor the Main content will expand when the content is bigger than the div's size? like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DEDX8/278/)

Comment: @FelipeLeão You can add "overflow-y: scroll" or "overflow-y: hidden" to #nav and #content.

Comment: Please add the content to your answer, since that link could go stale at some point.

Answer (score 5):

For "100% of the browser window", if you mean this literally, you should use fixed positioning. The top, bottom, right, and left properties are then used to offset the divs edges from the respective edges of the viewport:

```
#nav, #content{position:fixed;top:0px;bottom:0px;}
#nav{left:0px;right:235px;}
#content{left:235px;right:0px}
```

This will set up a screen with the left 235 pixels devoted to the nav, and the right rest of the screen to content.

Note, however, you won't be able to scroll the whole screen at once. Though you can set it to scroll either pane individually, by applying `overflow:auto` to either div.

Note also: fixed positioning is not supported in IE6 or earlier.

Comment: This is how a lot of HTML5 apps are layed out. For example, the extensions window in Google Chrome is actually a web page with the left-side nav taking fixed positioning. You can scroll the rest of the page to your heart's desire and the nav stays right there. That's fine as long as the user sizes the viewport  with enough height to accomodate your nav.