# CSS get total number of elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

is it possible to get the number of child elements in css? 
For example I want the last element to be 100% - (number of childs * 50px)

If there's no possibility in CSS3, can I do it with LESS or do I need JS

Comment: You need to use js in order to do that.

Comment: are you talking about `height` or `width` ? (*and what style do you want to apply because it might lead to different solutions*)

Comment: I have a table with a total width of 1000px. Every header should be 50px wide and the last one should fill the rest. If I have 1 header I want the header to be 1000px wide cause it's the last one. If I have 2 I want the first one to be 50px and the last one 950 px and so on

Comment: You mean an actual `table` tag ?

Comment: I talked about a selfmade table with div's to get a static header and vertical scrolling for headers, the JS way was helpful, I'll also try out the auto width on the last element, thx for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way in both CSS or LESS to do that. You can go with a JavaScript solution, which is fairly simple to implement.

Rough idea:

```
var allChildren = document.querySelectorAll('#myContainer > *');
var count = allChildren.length;

allChildren[count-1].style.width = 'calc(100% - '+ count * 50 +'px)';
```

Your specific problem (always better to post a specific problem!) can be solved easily with a HTML table:

HTML:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>      
      <td>3</td>
      <td>last</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

CSS:

```
table {
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

td {
  width:50px; 
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

td:last-child {
  width:auto;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/eTeBudiR/1/edit

If the data you want to display is not tabular in nature and you just want the layout to look like that, you can use CSS (`display:table`, `display:table-cell`) to achieve the same result.

HTML:

```
  <div id="myContainer">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>last</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
#myContainer {
  display:table;
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#myContainer > div {
  display:table-cell;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:50px;
}

#myContainer > div:last-child {
  width:auto;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/eTeBudiR/2/edit

Comment: Better do not mix javascript and css in this case.

Comment: @Pinal is there a reason for that? Other than browser support for the calc function, i see no problem with the solution. A JS-only solution that would be responsive is not that elegant and a CSS-only solution doesn't exist as far as i know.

Comment: I just want to say that `'calc(100% - '+ count * 50 +'px)'` make the same, that javascript do by `myContainer.offsetHeight - count*50`, but more slower.

Comment: Yes, but it is not responsive. Whenever i see percentage values i feel that the author designed that element to be responsive and as i said, a JS responsive solution would be messier to implement.

Answer (score 3):

***Update answer** after comment clarifying its a table*

You could use an actual `table` tag and make the last header `th` have `width:auto` while the rest have a fixed width. This is the normal way tables work and it will make it expand to fill the rest of the table..

If you have to use other tags, you could simulate a table by using the `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell` values..

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="headers">
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
        <div>4</div>
        <div>5</div>
        <div>6</div>
        <div>7</div>
        <div>8</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with css

```
.table{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
}
.headers{
    display:table-row;
}
.headers div{
    width:50px;
    display:table-cell;
}
.headers div:last-child{
    width:auto;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/KSbXM/

---

<strike>**Original Answer**</strike>

You could use the `:last-child` selector..

For example

```
<div class="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

and

```
.container div{
   height:50px;
}

.container div:last-child{
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Yes I know but I want to style the last element depending on how many elements I have in total

Comment: @tibos.. i see.. i misread the question.. will revise..

Comment: @JohnSmith added update dealing with tables..

Answer (score 2):

You do need JavaScript to get the number of elements or any other information about the displayed html. There is currently no way to do this with css and due its design there might never be .

last:child is an option, as others mentioned. You could somehow combine it with setting a relation to the parent-height (or width?). But there would be more information needed.

EDIT:

```
table {
   width: 1000px; /* or whatever you want it to be */
}
td{
   width: 50px;
}
td:last-child{
  width: auto;
}
```

http://codepen.io/johannesjo/pen/KLcrA

Answer (score 0):

You may try something from this.

```
.t1{
    counter-increment : test 1;
    background-color:red;

}
.t1:after{    
    content : counter(test);
    width : calc(counter(test)*50px);
}
```

working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fxNyw/)

Comment: doesn't work in chrome....

Comment: I have test it in chrome. Have you check demo?

Comment: checked the demo, did not work

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290873/css3-calc-not-working-in-latest-chrome/#16291105