# css calc invalid property value

Tags: css, css-calc

Can someone tell me why this CSS calc function isn't working? When I inspect element on Chrome, it says 'Invalid property value'.

```
width: calc((100vw - 14px * 2) / (270px + 11px * 2));
```

Comment: This is crazy. This is not the way to use calc property its not for this much of calculation

Comment: Chrome also rejects `width: calc((5) / (2));`

Comment: @Gaurav Aggarwal: why not

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53364752/8620333

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can't divide by units like `px`, only [numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Expressions).

Comment: I am having same error message for the code .war{min-height:calc(100vh-((100vh - 162.5)-300px))!important;}

Comment: @ Olanrewaju T: You need to have white space around your operators so your calculation should look like this: .war{min-height:calc(100vh - ((100vh - 162.5) - 300px)) !important;}

Answer (score 226):

For future googlers:

The unhelpful "invalid property value" message in DevTools might just mean that you need white space around your + - / * operators.

Incorrect (invalid property value):

```
width:calc(100vh-60px)  <== no spaces around minus sign
```

Correct:

```
width:calc(100vh - 60px) <== white space around the minus sign
```

The OP's question above does not have this problem, but while googling an answer to this error message this is the first resource I found, so it should have an answer dedicated to this common error.

References:

[CSS3 calc() not working in latest chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290873/css3-calc-not-working-in-latest-chrome)

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/12/getting-started-css-calc-techniques/

Comment: This solved the problem. Incredible how a whitespace could have such a great impact over the CSS.

Comment: Never in my life have I seen a language where whitespaces between operators matter...

Comment: I ran into this problem because my css minifier was removing the whitespace, thanks

Comment: @user2682863 how did you resolve this? I have the same issue. ASP.NET minifier is removing spaces for calc expressions.

Comment: @jessewolfe I changed minifiers, this answer just helped me identify the problem.

Comment: css is not a language

Answer (score 6):

When using calc() you **can't divide by pixels**, you can only divide by unitless numbers. Also, the number you are dividing has to have a certain unit like px, em, vh, vw.

For example, if you need to set a width of an element you should use:

```
width: (100px / 2); //this equals to 50px
```

An important note is to make sure you put **spaces between the operator signs**. This [calc() article](https://kolosek.com/css-calc/) provides further detailed explanation on the function.

Answer (score 6):

As @cssyphys noted above, you have to have spaces around your minus sign. However, if you are using ASP.NET MVC's bundler/minifier you find that it removes the spaces so you get the noted error.

If you are using plain CSS3, the following expression can be used in CSS and won't get minified:

```
width: calc((100%) - 50px);
```

HOWEVER, if you are using LESS (and perhaps other CSS preprocessors?), the preprocessor will "optimize" your expression and rip out your inner parens, again resulting in something ASP.NET will botch up. To get around that, use LESS's "don't process" tilde expression:

```
width: calc(~"(100%) - 50px");
```

I had to go back and change a bunch of calc() statements but so worth it to get back my ASP.NET minification.

Answer (score 2):

As Stephen Thomas has answered, you can't divide by units. To get around this, just divide the numbers as numbers and then assign the unit of measurement by multiplying the result by 1 unit of the units you're interested in. In your nested scenario you'd need to figure out what unit of measurement you were after in the end so that you could divide the numbers and then assign the result to a px or vw unit of measurement.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this error because one SCSS variable was set to zero:

WRONG:

```
$card-border-width: 0;
```

This eventually provoked Chrome's message *Invalid property value* in answer to the CSS result `border-radius: 0 0 calc(0.25rem - 0) calc(0.25rem - 0)`.

RIGHT:

```
$card-border-width: 0rem;
```

(giving `border-radius: 0 0 calc(0.25rem - 0rem) calc(0.25rem - 0rem)`)