# How do I debug CSS calc() value?

Tags: css, css-variables, css-calc

I have relatively complex formulas e.g. `transform: scale(var(--image-scale)) translateY(calc((1px * var(--element-height) * (var(--image-scale) - 1)) / 2 * var(--scrolled-out-y)))`

how do I debug calculated value? 
moreover is there a way to validate/highlight formulas errors?

I tried to output like this to the pseudoelement but no luck

```
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    background: yellow;
    padding: 5px;
    z-index: 100;
    content: calc((1px * var(--element-height) * (var(--image-scale) - 1)) / 2 * var(--scrolled-out-y));
```

the only way I found is to put part of calculation to unused numeric property e.g. `background-position-x` on the gif below so it will show calculated value on computed tab - useful but not really convenient one (notice `background-position-x` changes while the page scrolls):

[image]

```js
var sc = ScrollOut({
    cssProps: true
  })
  const results = Splitting();

  var parallaxedElements = document.querySelectorAll('.section');

  document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    parallaxedElements
    Array.from(parallaxedElements).forEach((el) => {
      var bcr = el.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (bcr.y < 0 && Math.abs(bcr.y) <= bcr.height) {
        el.style.setProperty("--scrolled-out-y", Math.round(Math.abs(bcr.y) * 10000 / bcr.height) / 10000);
      }
    });

  })
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");
  html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  
  body {
    font-family: "Roboto";
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  
  .section {
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    --image-scale: 1.2;
    --scrolled-out-y: 0;
  }
  
  .section__background {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  .section__background:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, 100% white);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    opacity: calc(1 + ((var(--viewport-y) * 1.5)));
  }
  
  .section__background>img {
    height: 150vh;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0px;
    user-select: none;
    transform: scale(var(--image-scale)) translateY(calc((-1px * var(--element-height) * (var(--image-scale) - 1)) * var(--scrolled-out-y)));
  }
  /* .indicator:after {
        position: fixed;
        display: block;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: pink;
        padding: 5px;
        z-index: 100;
        content: calc((1px * var(--element-height) * (var(--image-scale) - 1)) / 2 * var(--scrolled-out-y));
    } */
  
  .section__container {
    padding-bottom: 50vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: flex-start;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 4;
  }
  
  .section__heading {
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 1.2;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  
  .section__heading:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 2px;
    transform: translateX(calc(var(--scrolled-out-y) * 100% - 70%));
    background: #b38c6b;
  }
  
  .section__content {
    display: flex;
    color: white;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .section__content p+p {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
  
  .splitting {
    --char-percent: calc(var(--char-index) / var(--char-total));
  }
  
  .splitting .char {
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: calc(1 + ((var(--viewport-y) * 1.5) - var(--char-percent)));
  }
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/splitting/dist/splitting.css'>

<section data-scroll class="section section-1">
  <div class="section__background">
    <div class="indicator"></div>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1079" alt="placeholder image" />
  </div>
  <div class="container section__container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="title-block col-md-6 d-flex">
        <h1 data-scroll data-splitting class="section__heading">
          Why <br>CSS <br>matters
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
        <div class="section__content">
          <p>
            MThe ability to use variables in CSS is a useful and powerful feature that web developers have long been asking for. Well, it has finally arrived, and it’s awesome!
          </p>
          <p>
            In this article we’ll look at the history, importance, and use of CSS variables, and how you can leverage them to make your CSS development and maintenance faster and easier.
          </p>
          <p>
            Keep reading and you will understand why.
          </p>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section data-scroll class="section section-2">
  <div class="section__background">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1081" alt="placeholder image" />
  </div>
  <div class="container section__container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="title-block col-md-6 d-flex">
        <h1 data-scroll data-splitting class="section__heading">
          Why <br>CSS <br>matters
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
        <div class="section__content">
          <p>
            MThe ability to use variables in CSS is a useful and powerful feature that web developers have long been asking for. Well, it has finally arrived, and it’s awesome!
          </p>
          <p>
            In this article we’ll look at the history, importance, and use of CSS variables, and how you can leverage them to make your CSS development and maintenance faster and easier.
          </p>
          <p>
            Keep reading and you will understand why.
          </p>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section data-scroll class="section section-3">
  <div class="section__background">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1082" alt="placeholder image" />
  </div>
  <div class="container section__container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="title-block col-md-6 d-flex">
        <h1 data-scroll data-splitting class="section__heading">
          Why <br>CSS <br>matters
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
        <div class="section__content">
          <p>
            MThe ability to use variables in CSS is a useful and powerful feature that web developers have long been asking for. Well, it has finally arrived, and it’s awesome!
          </p>
          <p>
            In this article we’ll look at the history, importance, and use of CSS variables, and how you can leverage them to make your CSS development and maintenance faster and easier.
          </p>
          <p>
            Keep reading and you will understand why.
          </p>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section data-scroll class="section section-4">
  <div class="section__background">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1083" alt="placeholder image" />
  </div>
  <div class="container section__container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="title-block col-md-6 d-flex">
        <h1 data-scroll data-splitting class="section__heading">
          Why <br>CSS <br>matters
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
        <div class="section__content">
          <p>
            MThe ability to use variables in CSS is a useful and powerful feature that web developers have long been asking for. Well, it has finally arrived, and it’s awesome!
          </p>
          <p>
            In this article we’ll look at the history, importance, and use of CSS variables, and how you can leverage them to make your CSS development and maintenance faster and easier.
          </p>
          <p>
            Keep reading and you will understand why.
          </p>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section data-scroll class="section section-5">
  <div class="section__background">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1084" alt="placeholder image" />
  </div>
  <div class="container section__container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="title-block col-md-6 d-flex">
        <h1 data-scroll data-splitting class="section__heading">
          Why <br>CSS <br>matters
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
        <div class="section__content">
          <p>
            MThe ability to use variables in CSS is a useful and powerful feature that web developers have long been asking for. Well, it has finally arrived, and it’s awesome!
          </p>
          <p>
            In this article we’ll look at the history, importance, and use of CSS variables, and how you can leverage them to make your CSS development and maintenance faster and easier.
          </p>
          <p>
            Keep reading and you will understand why.
          </p>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section data-scroll class="section section-6">
  <div class="section__background">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1085" alt="placeholder image" />
  </div>
  <div class="container section__container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="title-block col-md-6 d-flex">
        <h1 data-scroll data-splitting class="section__heading">
          Why <br>CSS <br>matters
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 d-flex">
        <div class="section__content">
          <p>
            MThe ability to use variables in CSS is a useful and powerful feature that web developers have long been asking for. Well, it has finally arrived, and it’s awesome!
          </p>
          <p>
            In this article we’ll look at the history, importance, and use of CSS variables, and how you can leverage them to make your CSS development and maintenance faster and easier.
          </p>
          <p>
            Keep reading and you will understand why.
          </p>
          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/scroll-out/dist/scroll-out.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://unpkg.com/splitting@1.0.0/dist/splitting.js'></script>
```

Comment: Can you post some more real css and html code? This is not all the code needed to make it run..

Comment: There is no way (today) to debug that, other than pick the value using a script and check it computes properly. And do note, CSS is not a programming language.

Comment: share how you are defining the variable ... and used like that within content is false

Comment: @TemaniAfif added the full code so you can experiment

Comment: @RaymondNijland added the code

Comment: And FYI, you use `var(--element-height)` but none is declared

Comment: It's currently making me go a little nuts there's no way to debug this..

Answer (score 9):

> Is there a way to validate/highlight formulas errors?

You need to check to see if you aren't breaking any rules when defining your formula. Here it is from [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-syntax):

> At each operator, the types of the left and right argument are checked for these restrictions. If compatible, the type resolves as described below (the following ignores precedence rules on the operators for simplicity):
>
> - At `+` or `-`, check that both sides have the same type, or that one side is a `<number>` and the other is an `<integer>`. If both sides are the same type, resolve to that type. If one side is a `<number>` and the other is an `<integer>`, resolve to `<number>`.
> - At `*`, check that at least one side is `<number>`. If both sides are `<integer>`, resolve to `<integer>`. Otherwise, resolve to the type of the other side.
> - At `/`, check that the right side is `<number>`. If the left side is `<integer>`, resolve to `<number>`. Otherwise, resolve to the type of the left side.
>
> If an operator does not pass the above checks, **the expression is invalid**

It may sound a bit complex at the start but the rules are easy, and we can re-write them as follows with easy words:

- You cannot add/subtract two different types (`5px + 5s` has no meaning).
- You can only multiply with a number (`5px * 5px` has no meaning and is not equal to `25px`).
- You can only divide with a number that isn't `0` (`5px / 5px` has no meaning and it's not equal to `1` or `1px`).

If you don't break any of these rules, then your formula is correct. Let's not forget another important syntax rule:

> In addition, white space is required on both sides of the + and - operators. (The * and / operaters can be used without white space around them.)

---

Consider this, you simply need to identify if your CSS variable is a number/integer or defined with a type (length, frequency, angle or time). If it's not defined or contains a string value then the `calc()` will be invalid.

Check the specification for more details and a more precise explanation: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#calc-type-checking

---

> How do I debug calculated value?

To check the computed value, I don't think there is a way because the computed value of `calc()` can be different depending where you use it (which property). In other words, the *final* value doesn't exist until it's been used within a property.

We may think that some formulas are trivial like `calc(5px + 5px)` which will always compute to `10px` but other ones will be more difficult. Like `calc(5px + 50%)` where `%` will behave differently based on a property. Considering this, the browser will never compute the value until it's used within a property.

Even with the use of JS you cannot have the *final* value you want to debug; you can only get a computed value of properties:

```js
var elem = document.querySelector(".box");
var prop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("--variable");
var height = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("height");
console.log(prop);
console.log(height);
```

```css
.box {
  --variable: calc(5px + 5px);
  height:var(--variable);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This answer explain how to not create invalid CSS, it doesn't show how to actually _"debug calculated value"_, nor does it tell if there is _"a way to validate/highlight formulas errors"_, so IMHO it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @LGSon I am specifically answering this part *a way to validate/highlight formulas errors* ... by giving the rules we have our *way* to see if the formula is valid or not. So if the cacl() is invalid then the formula is wrong, otherwise it's correct

Comment: There is a big difference in "follow syntax guidelines" and "highlight its errors". An don' t get me wrong, it is a good read though doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @LGSon I am not getting you wrong ;) but I think this may help debbugin because the rules aren't always intuitive for some person. I always see people doing `height/width` thinking that it will intuitively work where there is no logic dividing a pixel with a pixed or multiplying a pixel with a pixel. So knowing this will help identifying trivial errors ... I have also added an answer for the other question (how do I debug calculated value?)

Comment: To answer the question, start with saying that _"CSS can't do that today, programmatically, one would need a script to do something with it"_. Let me know if, so I can upvote it ;)

Comment: @LGSon it's not about *CSS can't do that*. It's about understanding that CSS isn't C++ or any similar language. So thinking to bebug the value like we do with other langage is a wrong thinking because it doesn't behave that way. This what we need to understand in order to understand that `calc()` defined alone within a CSS variable has no meaning until it get used with a property. [will try to edit saying this]

Comment: Do note my first comment at the question...and btw, I didn't downvote now

Comment: @LGSon Upvoted your comment then, and even with a script we cannot check if the value computes correctly

Comment: @LGSon en Temani Well i was pretty close with mine workaround to debug CSS `calc()` and CSS variables.. if CSS counters also supported custom strings and floats it was perfect.. But i agree CSS is no C++ for that matter..

Comment: @TemaniAfif Since the equation is known (preset in CSS), the same could be in a script, and with that one could actually do the math by getting the values from the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

So to actually debug CSS variables you can use the helper class that I added below.

Then in console you can set and read variable like so:

```
CssVariables.setRootVar('--column-max-width', 'calc((90vw - var(--zoomer-width)) / (var(--columns-shown) + 1))');
console.log('width:', CssVariables.getRootVar("--column-max-width"));
```

Note that when you read a variable `var(--)` is already resolved.

When formula is invalid you will probably get a warning on console.

```
CssVariables.setRootVar('--column-max-width', 'calc(123px - var(123))');
// -> invalid value, declaration skipped
```

When you e.g. use non-existent variable you will get empty string when reading.

```
CssVariables.setRootVar('--column-max-width', 'calc(123px - var(--wtf))');
console.log('width:', CssVariables.getRootVar("--column-max-width"));
// -> width: <empty string>
```

**The CssVariables helper**

```
/**
 * CSS variables helper.
 */
class CssVariables {
    /**
     * Get :root variable.
     * @param {String} name Name of CSS var. e.g. "--columns-shown".
     * @returns {String} Current value.
     */
    static getRootVar(name) {
        return this.getVar(document.documentElement, name);
    }
    /**
     * @see #getRootVar
     */
    static getVar(element, name) {
        return window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(name);
    }
    /**
     * Set :root variable.
     * @param {String} name Name of CSS var. e.g. "--columns-shown".
     * @param {String} value New value. Should be a strin, but numbers would work as well.
     */
    static setRootVar(name, value) {
        this.setVar(document.documentElement, name, value);
    }
    /**
     * @see #setRootVar
     */
    static setVar(element, name, value) {
        element.style.setProperty(name, value);
    }
}

// if you are working with modules
//export { CssVariables }
```

Comment: the core of this answer is quite useful: `window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(name)`

Answer (score -1):

To get the fully-expanded CSS calc expression (not the final value), you can do

`window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue(name)`

(in your specific example, `name = 'transform'`)

Note this won't actually do the calculation, but will expand out the various CSS vars so you can see what is being computed. This is most helpful when intermediate vars may be set differently in different contexts

Note, if the prop you're trying to access is on a pseudoelement, you can do:

`window.getComputedStyle(baseElement, nameOfPseudoElementAsString).getPropertyValue(name)`

Comment: this returns the same value for e.g. `maxWidth` (`max-width` in css) - calc(100% - 10px) instead of the actual value

Comment: @DATEx2 yes, that is what I was trying to explain in the note: this will show the full expression being evaluated to get the value, not the final value itself. i have found this useful for debugging why i'm getting different values from what i was expecting. 

Made a small edit to hopefully make this more clear