# CSS Calc leads to invalid property in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have the following problem in Bootstrap 5:

When setting font-size using a utility class (`fs-1`) the font-size is not being applied. When I examine the class in dev-tools I see that

`calc(1.375rem+1.5vw)!important`

is an invalid property value. It works on Safari but not Chrome. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I finally worked it out. As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49239963/1426431):

> The unhelpful "invalid property value" message in DevTools might just mean that you need white space around your + - / * operators.

But why was the whitespace not there? It turns out that my CSS minifier was the problem. After removing it from my build-chain, everything worked fine.