# Why does the h1 element with the css "margin-top: calc((100%)/2)" display at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: html, css

Why doesn't my h1 show up in the middle of the screen when I type:

```
h1 {
    margin-top: calc((100%)/2);
    transition: color 0.5s linear, transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

(Talking about the margin-top property)

Instead, it's displayed at the bottom of the screen, can someone please explain why?

Comment: For that, you also need to post the rest of the code. It is working for me here: https://plnkr.co/edit/zMoIlF0SJUOqKQ0H3fdP?p=preview

Comment: Weird.

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/nZQHeXMCN0imGbvH?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: That is loading forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Margin percentages are [always based on width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003911/why-are-margin-padding-percentages-in-css-always-calculated-against-width).

**Flexbox**

You can achieve the desired effect with flexbox, as shown below.

```css
/* Remember that containers' heights are a percentage of their parents' heights */

html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Hello World</h1>  
</div>
```

**Alternative**

Flexbox supports very complex scenarios, but there is an easier way for this particular case, using the `vh` (viewport height) unit.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 32px;
  margin-top: calc(50vh - 16px);
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

**Additional Note**

I'm not sure why you used `calc()` in your example, but if you do, be sure to put [spaces around the operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290873/css3-calc-not-working-in-latest-chrome/16291105#16291105). Spaces are not required for the division operator, but it's a good habit to get into.