# How to use calc() in tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have this html:

```
  <div class="container h-screen w-screen">
    <div class="navBar h-7"></div>
    <div class="content-container"></div>
  </div>
```

I have set the `.navBar`'s height to `h-7`. Now I want to set `.content-container`'s height to `100vh-(h-7)`.

How can I use `calc()` to set it?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

#### [theme()](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme)

Use the `theme()` function to access your Tailwind config values using dot notation.

This can be a useful alternative to `@apply` when you want to reference a value from your theme configuration for only part of a declaration:

```
.content-container {
  height: calc(100vh - theme('spacing.7'));
}
```

Comment: This is the exact use case I was looking for. Not sure what 'spacing.7' is exactly, but thanks!

Comment: I think the `spacing.` is relevant to `h-` for me I use h-20 so `spacing.20` worked for me

Comment: @JohnY Brother  you should not put spaces in your class string. it is mentioned many times in this answer.

Comment: A bit late to the party but "spacing" is the unit in tailwind used for all padding, margin, gap, height, width, etc. In case other people reading this are wondering.

Answer (score 476):

Don't put space in calc:

```
class="w-[calc(100%+2rem)]"
```

Output:

```
.w-\[calc\(100\%\+2rem\)\] {
  width: calc(100% + 2rem);
}
```

Or you can use underscores `_` instead of whitespaces:

<sub>[Ref: Handling whitespace](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#handling-whitespace)</sub>

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="h-20 w-[calc(100%_-_10rem)] bg-yellow-200"></div>
```

We can use the theme variables as well:

```
h-[calc(100%-theme(space.24))]
```

Comment: It is also possible to omit the whitespaces like so `w-[calc(100%-10rem)]`

Comment: Remember guys, **without space!**

Comment: If you want to add this to the tailwind config file, then you should use spaces instead of underscores when extending the theme.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplified version of the instructions:

1. Open the `config.js` file.
2. In the `extend` section, add a new height property: `'100vh-h-7': 'calc(100vh - 3rem)'`.
3. In your HTML, you can now use this new class `100vh-h-7` for a content container.

Here's how you can apply these steps:

1. In `config.js`:

```js
extend: {
  height: {
    '100vh-h-7': 'calc(100vh - 3rem)',
    // other properties...
  },
  // other sections...
}
```

2. In your HTML:

```html
<div class="100vh-h-7">
  <!-- Your content here -->
</div>
```