# Using a theme value inside the calc of an arbitrary value in tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

This is my tailwindconfig:

```
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      height: {
        navHeight: "12vh",
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

In the code below, `min-h-[calc(100vh - h-navHeight)]` does not work, but min-h-[88vh] works. Is there any way to not hard-code the height?

```
 <div
      className='min-h-[calc(100vh - h-navHeight)] grid place-items-center after:absolute 
    after:h-[calc(100vh - h-navHeight)] after:w-full after:top-0 after:bg-[rgba(0,0,0,0.5)] '
    >
      <iframe
        className='z-10 max-w-full'
        width='1120'
        height='630'
        src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`}
        title='YouTube video player'
        frameBorder='0'
        allow='accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture;fullscreen;'
      ></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use calc() in tailwind CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65976223/how-to-use-calc-in-tailwind-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use tailwind config values in CSS use [`theme`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/functions-and-directives#theme) function provided by Tailwind. Example usage of `theme` in CSS:

```css
.content-area {
  height: calc(100vh - theme(spacing.12));
}
```

So this is how your statement would look like:

```
h-[calc(100vh-theme(height.navHeight))]
```

Also if you have [whitespace in arbitrary Tailwind values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#handling-whitespace) they won't work.