# Height of main container div not increasing dynamically when content inside the div increases

Tags: html, css, height

Below are screeshots of what I have got at the moment and what I want to achieve. The second image I have been able to do by increasing the height with pixels manually just for illustration purposes, but I would like this to be achieved automatically from the size of the content within the container...

Image1: 
[image]

Image2:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="top-body" style="clear:both">
   <div id="info">
    <p>Dixon Woods School of Dance was established 25 years ago in Newbold Verdon. Although lessons still take place in Newbold Verdon the main activities of the school now take place in their purpose built studios in Oadby.
        All lessons are given under the personal supervision of the principal Michelle Dixon-Woods. The school is recognised as having exceptionally high standards, which is reflected in examination and festival results achieved by the pupils.</p>
   </div>
</div>

<div id="footer1">
   <div id="footer-image">
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
top-body {
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #ffffff;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
top: 197px;
width: 960px;
padding-top: 7px;
}

info {
width: 327px;
float: right;
margin-right: 39px;
margin-top: 14px;
}

#info p {
font-size: 15px;
font-family: "myriad pro";
line-height: 15px;
text-align: justify;
}

#footer1 {
width: 960px;
height: 23px;
}

#footer-image {
width: 100%;
background-image: url('../images/footer-border1.png');
height: 23px;
}
```

Comment: Your problem is `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: `overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;` is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to put div

```
#info
    {
    clip:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I know tables suck and all, but a quick and dirty way is to replace the top-divs with table cells with 100% height, like so:

```
<table height="100%">
<tr><td height="100%" id="top-body">
   <div id="info">
    <p>...</p>
   </div>
</td></tr>
<tr><td id="footer1">
   <div id="footer-image">
   </div>
</td></tr></table>
```

Remember to also set the height of the body element to 100%

In CSS3 you can calculate the height to 100% minus something.
See [CSS How to set div height 100% minus nPx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192783/css-how-to-set-div-height-100-minus-npx)