# Height of main container div not increasing dynamically when content inside the div increasess

Tags: html, css, height

Below are screeshots of what I have got at the moment and what I want to achieve. The second image I have been able to do by increasing the height with pixels manually just for illustration purposes, but I would like this to be achieved automatically from the size of the content within the container. (And yes I have posted this question before but I accidently posted the wrong html and css coding for it).

Image1:
[image]

Image2:
[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="top-body" style="clear:both">

<div class="content" style="clear:both;">

<div class="services_text">
<h1><span class="red">CLASSES</span></h1>


<p class="classes">Dixon - Woods School of Dance train children from the age of 3 years upwards. All lessons consist of ballet, tap and modern/ jazz. Separate lessons are given in acrobatic and lyrical. </p>

<br><p class="classes">All Newbold Verdon children attend on Tuesdays. Oadby pupils attend Saturdays and mid-week for stage class lessons. </p>

<br><p class="classes">All pupils study the British Theatre Dance Association Syllabus, the school boasts an exceptionally high standard. To date the school has a 100% pass rate in examinations and medals with the above association with many children gaining the highest mark of distinction. </p>

<br><p class="classes">Children who wish to take their dancing further, attend stage class lessons. Stage class gives the opportunity for pupils to represent the school in dance festivals and is a further commitment to the school as they are also part of a troupe who dance for the school in competitions. Stage class pupils are also more involved in our annual show. </p> 

<br><p class="classes">Adult tap lessons are availible on wednesday evenings, your never to old to start..! </p>

<br><p class="classes">For further details please contact us, via our contact us section. </p>
</div>

<div class="services_outer">

<div class="services_text_padding"><span class="services_text_1">KITCHEN &amp; BATHROOM DESIGN</span></div>

<div class="services_text_padding"><span class="services_text_1">SOLID WOOD<br>
  &amp; LAMINATE FLOORING</span></div>

<div class="services_text_padding"><span class="services_text_1">PLYWOOD,<br>
  MDF &amp; TIMBER CUTTING</span></div>

<div class="services_text_padding"><span class="services_text_1">KEY CUTTING SERVICES</span></div>

<div class="services_text_padding"><span class="services_text_1">POWER TOOL REPAIRS &amp; SHARPENING</span></div>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="footer1">
    <div id="footer-image">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#top-body {
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #ffffff;
height: auto;
width: 960px;
padding-top: 7px;
}

.content {
width: 960px;
padding: 0 1px 0 1px;
margin: 0 3px;
height: 351px;
}

.services_text {
width: 207px;
float: left;
padding: 17px 0px 0 20px;
}

h1 {
font-size: 1.1em;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0;
color: #000;
padding-bottom: 10px;
font-style: normal;
}

.red {
color: #b5111a;
}

.services_outer {
width: 679px;
height: 351px;
background: url(../images/classes.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
margin: 1px 0 0 42px;
float: left;
}

.services_text_padding {
padding: 247px 0 0 13px;
float: left;
width: 126px;
}

.services_text_1 {
color: #FFF;
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.3;
}

p.classes {
font-size: 0.7em;
font-weight: normal;
margin: 0;
color: #000;
line-height: 1.3;
font-style: normal;
padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Height of main container div not increasing dynamically when content inside the div increases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16401917/height-of-main-container-div-not-increasing-dynamically-when-content-inside-the)

Answer (score 0):

This has been achieved by using float:left; on the top-body div and the footer div

Answer (score 0):

On your `.content` class you have `height:351px;` if you change that to `min-height:351px` that should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I agree with ddilsaver. If possible you could just get rid of the `height:351px;` attribute. That is what is making the div not increase.